# What is Crystal Reports doing when summing an Integer and a string?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I'm looking at a Crystal report someone else wrote, where a formula @a1 contains this:

IF SUM({@c1}, {@cIPA_Group}) > 0 THEN
   SUM({@d1}, {@cIPA_Group}) % SUM({@c1}, {@cIPA_Group})

@c1 and @d1 return an integer, but @cIPA_Group contains this:

IF {PLANNAME} LIKE ["*HEALTHCARE*","*HEALTH*CARE*"] THEN
   {DESCRIPTION}
ELSE
   ""

Since @cIPA_Group is returning a string, how does this work? Is it saying only do the summing
if the return string is "HealthCare"?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument in the SUM() expressions indicates the level of grouping for that sum.
A grand total would have no such argument.
A total for a group would return the total for that group.